# c# differenciate two lists with object

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have these two lists `result` and `resultNew`:

```
data.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.Name, "Name");
data.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.Code, "Code");
data.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.WorkingStatus, "Working Status");
var result = (from x in data.Worksheet<Employee>("Tradesmen")
              select x).ToList();


dataNew.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.Name, "Name");
dataNew.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.Code, "Code");
dataNew.AddMapping<Employee>(x => x.WorkingStatus, "Working Status");
var resultNew = (from x in dataNew.Worksheet<Employee>("On Leave")
                 select x).ToList();
```

where `Employee` is a simple c# code that contains `code`, `name` and `workingStatus` fields

I want to take the data which its `code` is the `resultNew` and not in the `result`

I tried this:

```
var newEmployees = resultNew.Except(Code = result.Select(s => s.Code)).ToList();
```

but I got syntax error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: If `resultNew` is `List<string>` *(Codes)*, then you can do: `resultNew.Except(result.Select(s=> s.Code).ToList()`, but that will give you difference of Codes.

Comment: @Habib no it is list on `Employee`

Comment: `Except` is used for dealing with 2 enumerables. Basically "take these 2 lists of the same type and only return me elements where items aren't in this other list".

Comment: @TyCobb but these are lists on `Employee` object, and I want to differenciate depending on `Employy code` not because some time we have employee with the same name but differeenct code. (code is like ID) got me pleaes?

Comment: No, I got it. Just informing you what `Except` actually does and why it is erroring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `HashSet` for Code of new employees and then use it like:

```
HashSet<string> resultCodes = new HashSet<string>(result.Select(r => r.Code));
List<Employee> newEmployees = resultNew.Where(r => !resultCodes.Contains(r.Code))
                                    .ToList();
```

You can also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for your class Employee base on property `Code` and then you can use `Except` like:

```
class Employee
{
    protected bool Equals(Employee other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Code, other.Code);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Employee) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Code != null ? Code.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string WorkingStatus { get; set; }

}
```

and then:

```
var newEmployees = resultnew.Except(result).ToList();
```

Remember the above implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` only considers `Code` property. See this question [How do you implement GetHashCode for structure with two string, when both strings are interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70303/how-do-you-implement-gethashcode-for-structure-with-two-string)

Comment: I was going to do it with a `IEnumerable<string>` by selecting the codes from resultNew (`var resultCodes = resultNew.Select(r => r.Code);`). Is HashSet more performant than my method?

Comment: @Brandon, yes it is. For a smaller data set you will not notice the difference. Without `HashSet` one can do: `resultNew.Where(r=> result.Select(s=> s.Code).Contains(r.Code))`

Comment: I didn't think about HashSet until I saw your answer. Thanks for the clarification with larger data sets. Glad I asked.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but maybe you mis understand my question, i want the employees who exist just in `resultNew` , but your code seems to give me the emplployees which exist just in `result` am i right please?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, with overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and using `Except` you will get only those employees which exist in  `resultNew` but don't exist in `result` like `new[] {1, 2, 3,}.Except(new[] {3, 4, 5}).ToList();` would give you `{1,2}`

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, also modified in the first option.

Comment: I am sorry but really the result of your code is incorrect, i added a new employee and ran your code, but the new employee didn't appear

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, which code you are trying ? first one or did you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and using `Except` ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, missed the `!` in the condition, try now. It is working just like Except. Tested on my machine.